# Keras error: Expected size[1] in [0, 0], but got 1

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to build the decoder within a larger `seq2seq` model in Keras but I keep getting the following error when I run the fit function. The model builds fine otherwise.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[1] in [0, 0], but got 1
[[Node: lambda_2/Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](lambda_1/Slice, 
metrics/acc/Const, lambda_2/Slice/size)]]
```

`lambda_x/Slice` seems to be referring to the lambda function in the loop.

My model has 4 inputs of shape `(N, 11), (N, 3), (N, 11), (N, 3)` and outputs a softmax distribution of shape `(N, 11, 1163)`.

Below is my code for the decoder which is where the splitter layer is used:

```
def _decoder_serial_input(self, encoder_states, state_h, state_c):
    """
    Compute one-by-one input to decoder, taking output from previous time-step as input
    :param encoder_states: All the encoder states
    :param state_h: starting hidden state
    :param state_c: starting cell state
    :return: Concatenated output which is shape = (N, Timestep, Input dims)
    """

    all_outputs = []
    states = [state_h, state_c] 
    inputs = self.decoder_inputs  # Shape = N x num_timestep

    repeat = RepeatVector(1, name="decoder_style")
    conc_1 = Concatenate(axis=-1, name="concatenate_decoder")
    conc_att = Concatenate(axis=-1, name="concatenate_attention")

    for t in range(self.max_timestep):

        # This slices the input. -1 is to accept everything in that dimension
        inputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.slice(x, start=[0, t], size=[-1, 1]))(inputs)

        embedding_output = self.embedding_decoder(inputs)
        style_labels = repeat(self.decoder_style_label) 

        concat = conc_1([embedding_output, style_labels])  # Join to style label

        decoder_output_forward, state_h, state_c = self.decoder(concat, initial_state=states)

        if self.attention:
            context, _ = self._one_step_attention(encoder_states, state_h)  # Size of latent dims
            decoder_output_forward = conc_att([context, decoder_output_forward])

        outputs = self.decoder_softmax_output(decoder_output_forward)  # Shape = (N, 1, input dims)

        all_outputs.append(outputs)
        states = [state_h, state_c]

    return Concatenate(axis=1, name="conc_dec_forward")(all_outputs)
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. The problem was that I was setting the output of the `Lambda` layer to the `inputs` variable which is wrong. This changed the shape of the input tensor to the lambda layer. On the first iteration it was `(N, 11)`, as desired, but on subsequent iterations of the loop it became `(N, 1)`, which resulted in an error.